# R JSON list element extraction in a loop

Tags: json, r, list

I am parsing JSON objects from [pipl.com](http://dev.pipl.com/io-docs).
Specifically I am passing a CSV of contacts using lapply fromJSON under the jsonlite library to the api.  Then I want to cbind specific elements into a flat dataframe.  I have tried mapply, sapply and lapply to then rbind as below but this isn't working as I expect for any other elements than the ones below.  I have tried it individually using the 'mini.test[[1](http://dev.pipl.com/io-docs)]$records$user_ids' syntax but the original contacts dataframe has hundreds of records so I was thinking a loop would be able to extract the elements I want.

I am looking to find only the user names for linkedin, facebook and twitter for each user.  Thus I was thinking some sort of grepl would help me subset it.  I have that vector created and posted the code below too.

I have read multiple r-bloggers articles on the different "apply" functions, looked at the R Cookbook pdf, and read questions on stackoverflow.  I am stumped so really appreciate any help.

```
library(jsonlite)

#sample data
first<-c('Victor','Steve','Mary')
last<-c('Arias','Madden','Johnson')
contacts<-cbind(first,last)


#make urls
urls<-paste('http://api.pipl.com/search/v3/json/?first_name=',contacts[,1],'%09&last_name=',contacts[,2],'&pretty=True&key=xxxxxxx', sep='')

#Parse api
mini.test<-lapply(urls,fromJSON,simplifyMatrix=TRUE,flatten=TRUE)


#Data frame vector name
names <- do.call(rbind, lapply(mini.test, "[[", 5))
display <-do.call(rbind, lapply(names, "[[", 3))

#Grepl for 3 sources
records <- lapply(mini.test, "[[", 7)
twitter <-grepl("twitter.com",records,ignore.case = TRUE)
facebook <-grepl("facebook.com",records,ignore.case = TRUE)
linkedin <-grepl("linkedin.com",records,ignore.case = TRUE)
```

I know because of pipl's response that contacts may have multiple profile user names.  For this purpose I just need it unlisted as a string not a nested list in the dataframe.  In the end I would like a flat file that looks like below.  Again, I am sincerely appreciate the help.  I have been reading about it for 3 days without much success.

```
twitter  <- c('twitter.username1','twitter.username2','NA')
linkedin <- c('linkedin.username1','linedin.username2','linkedin.username3')
facebook <- c('fb1','fb2','fb3,fb3a')

df<-cbind(display,twitter,linkedin,facebook)
```

Comment: Just how stupid must I be? I looked at the pipl.com site, saw that they allowed testing with key='samplekey' and ran your code. After filling up my console several times wtih efforts like `str(mini.test)` and `mini.test[[1]]` and looked at your 'records' object. I finally tried `object.size(mini.test)` and got `3106040 bytes`. How exactly do you expect to process that result????

Comment: Thx for the attempt.  I can do it for a single call per below.
`#find linkedin of 1st api response
li.profiles   <-subset(mini.test[[1]]$records,source.domain=="linkedin.com")
li.profiles$source.url`  I would need to know how to do it for mini.test[[1]], mini.test[[2]] onward to go through the entire contact sheet.  Did I not explain it well.  Apologies if so.